# numpy split error - too many indices for array

Tags: numpy

I am trying to use the split function within numpy as follows:

```
desc = np.array(['Alu Bokhara','Kurma Polao'])
```

Then I am trying to extract and print the first word from each element within the array as follows:

```
np.array([np.split(i,' ')[0] for i in desc])
```

Then I am getting the error:

```
tuple index out of range
```

Any hint over this issue?

Thanks

Comment: np.split is for an array.  i.split() is for a string, a element of your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative vectorized approach, you could use [`np.core.defchararray.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.split.html) -

```
[i[0] for i in np.core.defchararray.split(desc, sep=' ')]
```

Basically, we are splitting each element based on the `space character`, thus separating out words in a *sub-list* each and then simply selecting the first element from each *sub-list*.

Sample run -

```
In [117]: desc
Out[117]: 
array(['Alu Bokhara', 'Kurma Polao'], 
      dtype='|S11')

In [118]: [i[0] for i in np.core.defchararray.split(desc, sep=' ')]
Out[118]: ['Alu', 'Kurma']
```

Runtime test -

```
In [142]: desc = np.array(['Then I', 'am trying to' ,'extract and', 'print',\
     ...:     'the first word from each', 'element within the', 'array'])

In [143]: %timeit pd.Series(desc).str.split().str[0].values #@piRSquared's soln
1000 loops, best of 3: 509 µs per loop

In [144]: %timeit [i[0] for i in np.core.defchararray.split(desc, sep=' ')]
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.8 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pandas`.  This is an example of use a `pandas.Series` to do the splitting and getting back an array.

```
import pandas as pd

np.array(pd.Series(desc).str.split().tolist())

array([['Alu', 'Bokhara'],
       ['Kurma', 'Polao']], 
      dtype='<U7')
```

For just the first word

```
pd.Series(desc).str.split().str[0].values

array(['Alu', 'Kurma'], dtype=object)
```